# rounded corner submenu and horizontal menu

Tags: css

I'm creating a joomla template based on protostar and I have these two problems that I cant solve.

1. I want a simple rectangle sub menue not rounded one
2. I tried almost everything I knew and fried my brain but it didn't work.I want a horizontal menue and dont want to use nav-pills class in joomla because of its rounded shape.

[image]

Comment: So where's your markup and CSS?

Comment: I don't get what you want. do you want rounded corners or not?

Comment: Reading your question, I interpreted, you want round menu. I have changed my answer.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this problem generally.protostar template in joomla uses bootstrap css.